# Why isn't my table updated after an ajax call?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-table

I have a bootstrap-table.js table based on a HTML table build up from a MySQL database. See code:

```
<table id="table2" class="table table-striped table-hover table-no-bordered"
data-toggle="table"
data-search="true"
data-pagination="true"
data-page-size="25"
data-show-refresh="true"
data-url="stemmen.php"
data-side-pagination="client"
data-unique-id="id"
>                                           <thead>
<tr>
    <th data-field="id" data-visible="false">ID</th>
   <th data-field="timestamp">datum &amp; tijd</th>
   <th data-field="email">e-mailadres</th>
   <th data-field="stem">stem</th>
   <th data-formatter="operateFormatter" data-events="operateEvents"></th>
</tr>
</thead>
</table>
```

As you can see in the last column there's a button to remove the row. This triggers an ajax script.

```
function operateFormatter(value, row, index) {
    return [
        '<button class="btn btn-xs btn-danger voteremove"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button>'
    ].join('');
};

window.operateEvents = {
        'click .like': function (e, value, row, index) {
        alert('You click like icon, row: ' + JSON.stringify(row));
        console.log(value, row, index);
    },
    'click .edit': function (e, value, row, index) {
        alert('You click edit icon, row: ' + JSON.stringify(row));
        console.log(value, row, index);
    },
    'click .voteremove': function (e, value, row, index) {
        var id = [row.id];
        if(confirm("Weet je zeker dat je deze stem wilt verwijderen?")){
        var $table = $(this).closest('table').attr('id');
               $.ajax({
                  type: 'POST',
                   url: 'functions.php?action=removeVote',
                   data: 'vote_id=' + id,
                   cache: false,
                   success: function () {
                        $($table).bootstrapTable('remove', {
                            field: 'id',
                            values: [row.id]
                        });


                       $(formMessages).removeClass('alert-danger');
                           $(formMessages).addClass('alert-success');
                        $(formMessages).text('succesvol verwijderd');
                       $(formMessages).show();

                    },
                   error: function(){
                           $(formMessages).removeClass('alert-success');
                           $(formMessages).addClass('alert-danger');
                        $(formMessages).text('er is een fout opgetreden!');
                       $(formMessages).show();
                   }
               });
        }
    }
};
```

Now my issue. The ajax action is triggered and performing well, the message is displayed, but the row is not removed from the table, unless you refresh the page.

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: Before getting into the details about solving the issue that you mentioned I want to make a humble question and suggestion. Why are you getting front end code from the database? And is that something that you are able to change? Getting front-end code from the db can become a tremendous maintainability nightmare.

Comment: Because, for some reason i can't load data from a generated json file, but that's a different question..

Comment: It definitely is a different question just trying to help you to avoid going on a direction that's likely to cause a lot of headaches. Data and code are two separate things though so why not make a call to a backend API and retrieve just the data as opposed to data+code from the db?

Comment: You're definitely right.. starting to assume that this is the cause of the problem too, so might be better to look into this issue first...

Comment: I usually treat the database as a dumb data repository and nothing else. I try to avoid adding any sort of logic/code (of any type) there as much as possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, it's solved! Thanks to the motivation of univ to change the way of loading data, and some other small issues. Below you'll find the code.

**JS**

```
function operateFormatter(value, row, index) {
    return [
        '<button class="btn btn-xs btn-danger voteremove"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button>'
    ].join('');
};

window.operateEvents = {
        'click .like': function (e, value, row, index) {
        alert('You click like icon, row: ' + JSON.stringify(row));
        console.log(value, row, index);
    },
    'click .edit': function (e, value, row, index) {
        alert('You click edit icon, row: ' + JSON.stringify(row));
        console.log(value, row, index);
    },
    'click .voteremove': function (e, value, row, index) {
        if(confirm("Weet je zeker dat je deze stem wilt verwijderen?")){
            var id = [row.id];
            var formMessages = $('#messages');
            var table = '#table2';
               $.ajax({
                  type: 'POST',
                   url: 'functions.php?action=removeVote',
                   data: 'vote_id=' + id,
                   cache: false,
                   success: function () {
                        $(table).bootstrapTable('remove', {
                            field: 'id',
                            values: id
                        });
                        $(formMessages).removeClass('alert-danger');
                        $(formMessages).addClass('alert-success');
                        $(formMessages).text('succesvol verwijderd');
                        $(formMessages).show();
                    },
                   error: function(){
                        $(formMessages).removeClass('alert-success');
                        $(formMessages).addClass('alert-danger');
                        $(formMessages).text('er is een fout opgetreden!');
                        $(formMessages).show();
                   }
               });
        }
    }
};
```

**HTML**

```
<table id="table2" class="table table-striped table-hover table-no-bordered"
data-toggle="table"
data-search="true"
data-pagination="true"
data-page-size="25"
data-show-refresh="true"
data-url="stemmen.php"
data-side-pagination="client"
data-unique-id="id"
>                                           <thead>
<tr>
    <th data-field="id" data-visible="false">ID</th>
   <th data-field="timestamp">datum &amp; tijd</th>
   <th data-field="email">e-mailadres</th>
   <th data-field="stem">stem</th>
   <th data-formatter="operateFormatter" data-events="operateEvents"></th>
</tr>
</thead>
</table>
```

Comment: I feel like I did some good in the world today haha happy to help bro I am glad that you were open to considering other options :-)

As a side note in general in coding when you follow best practices things tend to work much better and your life becomes much easier because the alternative to following best practices is a pretty dark path that very quickly gets out of control as the codebase grows :-)